# Prove of statement $\sin(90 - \alpha) = \cos \alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

I've red a book and seen this statement $\sin (90 - \alpha) = \cos \alpha$ but I've not seen prove it. Can you say me when I can find prove it and explanation? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$sin(90°-\alpha)=sin(90°+(-\alpha))$$
$$=sin(90°)cos(-\alpha)+cos(90°)\sin(-\alpha)=cos(-\alpha)=cos(\alpha)$$

Note, that $sin(90°)=1$ , $cos(90°)=0$ and $sin(\alpha+\beta)=sin(\alpha)cos(\beta)+sin(\beta)cos(\alpha)$

Comment: why $ \cos(- \alpha) = cos (\alpha)$?

Comment: Ths cosine-function is an even function. You can see this best with the taylor-series $cos(x)=1-x^2/2+x^4/24...$

Answer (score 4):

Think about a right triangle. If you have the angle $A$, then $90-A$ is the angle $B$ in the drawing below.

[image]

If you're considering $\sin(90-A)$, this is the same as $\sin B$ (since $90-A = B$), but by definition $\sin B = \frac{b}{c}$. (Think SOHCAHTOA.) What do you know about $\cos A$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\sin  \left( 90^{ \circ  }-\alpha  \right) =\sin { \left( 90^{ \circ  } \right)  } \cos { \left( \alpha  \right)  } -\cos { \left( 90^{ \circ  } \right)  } \sin { \left( \alpha  \right)  } =\cos { \left( \alpha  \right)  }  $$